# have to restart the jaspersoft studio if the customized jasper function library get changed

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

guys.  **I am using jaspersoft studio 5.6.0 final.**

I am having a weird issue that whenever I made new changes to my own functions library. jaspersoft studio DOES NOT recompile it automatically. If I clean and build the project manually, the generated report won't take advantage of the new changes.

It happens to me (using windows7) and my teammates (using mac)

As a result, I have to restart the whole program all the time.

And, even if I do that, my function library sometime works and sometime don't. (no idea why)

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux. In my case, when I restart, it always works. It gets really complicated to debug Java Beans, for example. I believe it's related to the way the environment deals with the Java classpath. If there was a way to force the classpath reload, probably it would help.

Comment: I came through the Jaspersoft Community forums, and it looks like more people have been addressing the same problem with Jaspersoft Studio (an example: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/825329/reloable-jars-jaspersoft-studio-ireports).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this isuue you should enable build automatically

on the top click on project and check build automatically